Selenium- Maven project. It gave the below exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
package seleniumJava;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

//import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class SelIntroduction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Divya\\Desktop\\Selenium\\Downloads\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver-win64\\chromedriver.exe");

        //Invoking Browser
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    }

}

Exception:::
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at Project1/seleniumJava.SelIntroduction.main(SelIntroduction.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 4 more

